# Trusting data from an API

Tags: api

I read an interesting security article recently that amongst other recommendations suggested data from an external API should be treated like user inputed data.

Well of course that makes a lot of sense. But is anyone sanitising data from well known companies, is there a real risk there?

What kind of things should be mitigated against, just SQL injections and code injections? Is there anyway server-side code could be manipulated if data is not sanitised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sanitize it like it was user inputed data. It doesn't need to be ment evil by the API provider or it could also be the fault of the user giving the data to the API provider. Who says the API provider sanitized the data? Who says the API provider needs to sanitize the same way like you? Maybe the special character is valid for him.

A "'" might be a valid character for the API provider and a persons name could be called "Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--" and you got SQL injected without evil intentions of the API provider but by a mum naming her son like this.

For another example you get data from an API provider and display it on your website and you don't sanatize it: It might contain a special character which breaks your webpage or whole website. It might contain evil javascript/html code which can infect the user machine with a virus.
It might contain evil javascript/html code which has the same rights as the user viewing it. A logged in administrator views the page and the javascript deletes or manipulates the website/creates a new user with admin rigts/many more things.
Depending how the API data is stored/processed it might read/write security relevant files on the system or create/change files executed on the server. For example a file could be created which is executed by the webserver instead of sent directly to the client.
So always sanatize third party data.

Edit to make sure there is no misunderstanding: i am talking about data in the meaning of information representation, not about information per se. Information would be, that an actress is Robert's mum. Information representation could be

> {actress: "Robert's mum"}

So make sure this data does not cause an SQL-injection at your side. If you trust the information that the actress was really Robert's mum is another topic.

Comment: Do you feel that this is needed for all APIs? For example, how about Google's authentication API?

Comment: @NeilSmithline At least sanatize the data from it. If you trust the (authentification) information is another topic and I also hope you have read their SLAs and tought about when it fails. Such services had multiple outages in the past. For example at the facebook-login outage last year big parts of the internet were affected because it was the only login option for some sites or the site waited until the connection to facebook login timed out. An interesting video is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4GB_NDU43Q ("Single Point of Failure: The (Fictional) Day Google Forgot To Check Passwords").

Comment: I don't say you shouldn't use it but you should be careful about it and should not blindly add it to your website, especially as your only authentification option.

Comment: Ok I agree about data which is stored and then re-published. But what about the server-side code that reads the API data, is there a first line of defence that would protect the rest of the PHP code for example. Or is that just too unlikely to worry about?

Comment: Depends on how you process the data. If for example a file name depends on the data, it might cause read/write to security related files/databases.Or to access a remote file instead of the local one.Or create a file which is executed like putting a malicious PHP file in the web directory and then called by the attacker. SQL injections are already mentioned. I have seen examples where the name of the table was specified by the user data.And there are many moreSo only trust the data as much as how much you trust the API provider not to (un)intentionally harm you and his data providers or an MitM

Comment: The question "Or is that just too unlikely to worry about?" is about risk management. If the worst damage and the propability of the event are low enough and the effort too high, some might choose to say that. But it would be against best practices and be prepared to handle the damage. Many companies tried to go the cheap route until hackers published their whole user-database or did other damage.

Comment: @NeilSmithline - it isn't needed for all APIs. Particularly APIs that I personally have written. :D

Comment: @TTT added some clarification based on this topic to the answer

Comment: @H.Idden - I was just joking around and following Neil's lead. My point was that any API I write would already be sanitized, so you wouldn't have to worry about this. But from your point of view, my API would be 3rd party so you'd still have to sanitize it. Neil was implying the same thing- you have much bigger fish to fry than worry about SQL injection coming back to you from the Google Authentication API.

Comment: @TTT yes and no. Most frameworks nowaday makes it very easy  for most common types of APIs to get it right so it is more of a loss of time thinking about cases to use or not to use than just using them. Like using builtin functions for JSON parsing than programming your own, using SQL prepared statements, using htmlencode when outputing and correct use of authentification/session handling. With these simple tools and a decent programming style you already cover more than 95% of all cases and archieved basic security. If you should do depends on API/risk/project/what data it should protect/...

Comment: So for your personal APIs these simple tools are most likely enough and shouldn't be any effort.

Comment: Btw. it saves you from searching for unintentional problems like beeing able to return "Robert's mum" with your API.

Comment: As @TTT suggests, once you are trusting an API for authentication, why bother worrying sanitizing. And if you can't trust the Google Authentication API to pass you sanitized data as their API states, then you better not be using it for authentication.

Comment: H. Idden - you should assume that the Google data will meet Google's API. If the API allows for strings with apostrophes or other punctuation in them, then you should expect it. That doesn't mean that you have to be sanitizing the return value from Google as if it was user input.

Comment: @NeilSmithline that's what I mean with sanatizing beside of checking syntax: making sure that it doesn't break your system for example when it contains an apostrophe by using parameterized SQL-queries and htmlspecialchars for output on the website and things like that. The syntax check is for ensuring if it meets the API. So I think we are talking about the same thing because that's about the same you should do with user data?